# I can't get the value of textbox from the footer row of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i can't get the value of textbox from the footer row of gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1214px"       
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" 
 OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"                                  
  <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert">
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblEditSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname") %>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSName" runat="server"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and the code behind is........
i can't get the value of textbox from the footer row of gridview

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName==("AddNew"))
    {
        TextBox txtName =(TextBox) GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSName");
string strName=txtName.Text;   //strName is Empty while i m enters data into the  textbox txtSName
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this comment to help others who may encounter the same issue.

Make sure the grid is not loading again on post back.

code in the page load  should look like this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  LoadGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mark up is biting you.You are having two footer templates within a template field.
Do this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditImageButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"
            ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.png"Style="height: 16px" ToolTip="Edit" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
            CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete.Are you sure you want to delete?')" 
            ImageUrl="~/images/DeleteTS.png" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID="AddNewImgBtn" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/saveHS.png"
               ToolTip="Add New" AlternateText="Add New" Width="16px" Height="16px" 
               CommandArgument="InsertNew" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" />
    </FooterTemplate>             
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblEditSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname") %>' />
     </EditItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtSName" runat="server"/>
      </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

And then you can gracefully locate your footer row.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
           if (e.CommandArgument=="InsertNew")
         {
         GridView testGrid=(Gridview)sender;
           TextBox txtName =(TextBox)testGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSName");
        string strName=txtName.Text;   
          }
         }
```

See working example [Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9pcdmj4ix98swm/WebSite3.zip)

Comment: how to get the value of textbox

Comment: Try now to get the text box using your original code.It should work.Replace Commandname with commandArgument

Comment: Now i have done that but now also the strName is empty string ("") or null

Comment: I have updated my answer.Just in case your grid view is buried under another control.Use the sender argument to find it first then locate the text box.That should work 100%also fix your markup code remove that initial misplaced closing tag of the template field in your post.

Comment: no its not work,value of string strName is empty string ("") or null

Comment: Is  textName also  null.When you put a break point on that line where you find the control what are you getting.Are you putting anything in the textbox.Please edit your markup code on your post.It is still wrong.

Comment: i am entering value in the textbox but textName also null.

Comment: Please correct your markup code in this post.I hope that is not what you are using.

Comment: I have prepared a working example for you.I am putting it on dropbox.

Comment: i think there is no any error  in my markup code......Please tell me Where is the error..

Comment: i m new on stackoverflow,please tell me where is the dropbox

Comment: Wait I will post the link.Your mark up has a misplaced template field closing tag.

Comment: I have updated my answer.You can get the link and open Default2.aspx.

Comment: but the link does not open

Comment: Send your email address to abidmix@gmail.com .This conversion is becoming to long which should become a chat on SO.But I can't chat to you because of your new profile.

Comment: website is not opened in my Office for chating, my email id is ahtshamali86@gmail.com