# I want to get the value of Textbox of Gridview footer row in C# ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the value of textbox from the footer row of gridview in C# ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618757/how-to-find-the-value-of-textbox-from-the-footer-row-of-gridview-in-c-sharp-asp)

I want to get the value of Textbox of Gridview footer row in C# ASP .NET but the return value of textbox is null or empty.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1214px"       
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="true" 
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_Update" runat="server" Text="Update"/>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_Delete" runat="server"CommandArgument="AddNew" Text="Insert"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEditSID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sid")%>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sid")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSID" runat="server" MaxLength="50"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name">
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="lblEditSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname")%>'/>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSName" runat="server"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Mobile No">
            <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditMobile" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("smno")%>'/>                 
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMobile" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("smno")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Email-ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("mailid")%>'/> 
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("mailid")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
            </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>       
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

this is the code Code behind,  I want to get the value of Textbox of Gridview footer row in C# ASP .NET but the reurn value of textboxs is null or empty

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    if (e.CommandArgument.Equals("AddNew")) {
        GridView test=(GridView)sender;
        TextBox txtSid = (TextBox)(test.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSID"));
        TextBox txtName = (TextBox)(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtSName"));
        TextBox txtMobile = (TextBox)(GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtMobile"));
        TextBox txtEmail = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail"));            
        string strSid =txtSid.Text;
        string strName = txtName.Text;
        string strMobile = txtMobile.Text;
        string strEmail = txtEmail.Text;
     }
}
```

Textxtbox values are `null` or empty string, `strName` and others strings are empty when I enter the values into the textboxes.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618757/how-to-find-the-value-of-textbox-from-the-footer-row-of-gridview-in-c-sharp-asp **and** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621068/i-cant-get-the-value-of-textbox-from-the-footer-row-of-gridview **and** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603538/textbox-txtsid-textboxgridview1-footerrow-findcontroltxtsid **NOTE** This question has been asked 4 times now by the same user.

Comment: Are the textboxes null after you have tried to find them or is the text empty? @SimonWhitehead: Those are no duplicates as far as i can see. They have just a similar title but different reasons.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's the same question, same issue, just more code from the OP. There is no communication or upvotes with people who've answered the previous questions. The OP hasn't even integrated their answers..

Comment: Did you check if you are binding the grid again (in short do you have a `if(! IsPostBack)` clause in your page load)

Comment: no i do not have if(! IsPostBack) clause                                          Thnks u r right program is running successfully

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Haven't seen that it's the same OP.